# Number paragons of in HCPC cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca, hierarchical-clustering

In HCPC analysis, it is possible to use the function res.hcpc$desc.ind$para to identify the five representative individual of each clsuter. Any way to increase the number of paragons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the function HCPC of the library FactoMineR.
You can specify the number of parangons by writing nb.par= (default is 5).
So, for example:

```
HCPC(data, nb.clust = 5, nb.par=10, graph = TRUE)
```